# Smooth Scrolling To An Anchor in Another Page

Tags: jquery, css

I have figured how to smooth scroll from a link to an anchor but it is working in within the same page.

For example, if I am in the home page, this link will smooth scroll: mysite.com/#section

But if I am in the about page (mysite.com/about), the same link to the home page (mysite.com/#section) won't scroll smoothly, just the plain default.

I have this so far:

```
jQuery('a').click(function(){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery( this.hash ).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

I ran out of ideas, please help

Comment: read window.location (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) and then run whatever code you want on document ready.

Comment: I am using document ready, but I still cant seem to implement window.location, can you share the code? And the issue seems to be on Firefox only

Answer (score 3):

You need to use CSS: **[Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2)**

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: To elaborate, yes you can avoid using JS by simply creating a link to another page like /mypage#section and use this CSS code to have a smooth scrolling behavior.

Comment: @Skoua it is not working in Firefox when linking between pages, only when scrolling on the same page, any thought please?

Comment: @karlosuccess Uuhh.. it should work from firefox 36.0?? Latest firefox version is 100 so that should be something weird. Did you push your edited CSS version? See: https://www.impressivewebs.com/force-browser-newest-stylesheet/

Comment: @Skoua In Firefox, it works and scrolls nicely when the link is in the same page. But when the link comes from a different page it just does the default ugly anchoring. In any other browser it works. I will keep checking and come back with updates. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this, checking if there's a `#section` in the URL and then scrolling to the target.

```
if(window.location.hash != '' && window.location.hash != '#') {
  let target = window.location.hash;

  if(!$(target).length) {
    return;
  }
  
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
  });
}
```

`if(!$(target).length)` is important, you might get an error if there's no div with the right id on the page.

Comment: Nope : Uncaught SyntaxError: return not in function

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me in case someone is looking for the answer:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // Scrolling for anchor links in within the same page
    jQuery('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function(){
        _hash = this.hash;
        _scroll_it( _hash );
    });

    // scrolling for anchor links coming from a different page
    var _hash = window.location.hash;
    if( _hash.length > 0 ){     
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        
        setTimeout( function() { 
            _scroll_it( _hash );
        }, 500 );       
    }
    
    function _scroll_it( _hash ){
        jQuery('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery( _hash ).offset().top
        }, 500 );
    }

});
```